# Is there a way to show a PyQt5 QMessageBox at the start of the program without interacting with it?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am making an app and I need to show the user at startup a pop-up message to tell them the instructions of the program. Is there a way to make the pop-up box to show at the beginning of the program? I have the message box function ready, I just need a way to display it at the beginning

I did all the research possible before coming here to ask but I couldn't find anything on the topic. I'm using Python `3.7` and PyQt5 `5.13.0` on Windows 10

```py
class Ui_AutoClicker(object):
    def setupUi(self, AutoClicker):
        AutoClicker.setObjectName("AutoClicker")
        AutoClicker.resize(586, 182)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.ico"),
                       QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        AutoClicker.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AutoClicker)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.push_start_end = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push_start_end.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 161, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.push_start_end.setFont(font)
        self.push_start_end.setObjectName("push_start_end")
        self.label_delay = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_delay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 191, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_delay.setFont(font)
        self.label_delay.setObjectName("label_delay")
        self.input_delay = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_delay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.input_delay.setFont(font)
        self.input_delay.setText("")
        self.input_delay.setObjectName("input_delay")
        self.label_click_count = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_click_count.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 0, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_click_count.setFont(font)
        self.label_click_count.setObjectName("label_click_count")
        self.lcd_click_counter = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd_click_counter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 50, 261, 121))
        self.lcd_click_counter.setProperty("intValue", 42069)
        self.lcd_click_counter.setObjectName("lcd_click_counter")
        self.lcd_click_counter.setProperty('digitCount', 10)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 0, 20, 251))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.push_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push_close.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 120, 121, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.push_close.setFont(font)
        self.push_close.setObjectName("push_close")
        AutoClicker.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.keyboard = KController()

        self.retranslateUi(AutoClicker)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AutoClicker)

        self.push_close.clicked.connect(self.close_app)
        self.push_close.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        self.push_start_end.clicked.connect(self.start_clicker)
        self.lcd_click_counter.setProperty('intValue', 1)


    def retranslateUi(self, AutoClicker):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AutoClicker.setWindowTitle(_translate("AutoClicker", "Auto Clicker"))
        self.push_start_end.setText(
            _translate("AutoClicker", "Start/Stop (F4)"))
        self.label_delay.setText(_translate("AutoClicker", "Delay in 
             seconds"))
        self.label_click_count.setText(_translate(
            "AutoClicker", "Number of clicks clicked"))
        self.push_close.setText(_translate("AutoClicker", "Close (F6)"))

    def show_initial_message(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Initial information')
        msg.setText("Please use the 'Close (F6)' button to close the program."
                    "Closing it by pressing the red X button on the top will "
                    "leave the "
                    "autoclicker running until the key 'F6' is pressed.")
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        x = msg.exec_()
```

Comment: do you mean before showing main window or when main window is already displayed ? Did you try to run it in `__init__` or even before you create class with main window ? What did you try ? I don't see in code that you try to run it.

Comment: I didn't try to run it in the code because I don't know how to show the message box without clicking a button.

Comment: simply use `self.show_initial_message()` in your `__init__()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the answer to my problem. I tried that but without the ```self.``` you are truly a hero to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_AutoClicker(object):
    def setupUi(self, AutoClicker):
        AutoClicker.setObjectName("AutoClicker")
        AutoClicker.resize(586, 182)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.ico"),
                       QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        AutoClicker.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AutoClicker)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.push_start_end = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push_start_end.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 161, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.push_start_end.setFont(font)
        self.push_start_end.setObjectName("push_start_end")
        self.label_delay = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_delay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 191, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_delay.setFont(font)
        self.label_delay.setObjectName("label_delay")
        self.input_delay = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_delay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.input_delay.setFont(font)
        self.input_delay.setText("")
        self.input_delay.setObjectName("input_delay")
        self.label_click_count = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_click_count.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 0, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_click_count.setFont(font)
        self.label_click_count.setObjectName("label_click_count")
        self.lcd_click_counter = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd_click_counter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 50, 261, 121))
        self.lcd_click_counter.setProperty("intValue", 42069)
        self.lcd_click_counter.setObjectName("lcd_click_counter")
        self.lcd_click_counter.setProperty('digitCount', 10)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 0, 20, 251))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.push_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.push_close.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 120, 121, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.push_close.setFont(font)
        self.push_close.setObjectName("push_close")
        AutoClicker.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
# ? KController        self.keyboard = KController()

        self.retranslateUi(AutoClicker)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AutoClicker)

# ? close_app       self.push_close.clicked.connect(self.close_app)
        self.push_close.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)  # QtCore.
# ? start_clicker       self.push_start_end.clicked.connect(self.start_clicker)
        self.lcd_click_counter.setProperty('intValue', 1)


    def retranslateUi(self, AutoClicker):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        AutoClicker.setWindowTitle(_translate("AutoClicker", "Auto Clicker"))
        self.push_start_end.setText(
            _translate("AutoClicker", "Start/Stop (F4)"))
        self.label_delay.setText(_translate("AutoClicker", "Delay in seconds"))
        self.label_click_count.setText(_translate(
            "AutoClicker", "Number of clicks clicked"))
        self.push_close.setText(_translate("AutoClicker", "Close (F6)"))

    def show_initial_message(self):
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Initial information')
        msg.setText("Please use the 'Close (F6)' button to close the program."
                    "Closing it by pressing the red X button on the top will "
                    "leave the "
                    "autoclicker running until the key 'F6' is pressed.")
        msg.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
        x = msg.exec_()



class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_AutoClicker):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = Window()

    application.show_initial_message()                             # +++

    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show it before showing main window then put it in function outside class and run it before you create main window and show it.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox

# --- classes ---

class MyApp(QWidget):
    pass

# --- functions ---

def show_message():
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setWindowTitle('Initial information')
    msg.setText("Please use the 'Close (F6)' button to close the program.\n\n"
                "Closing it by pressing the red X button on the top will "
                "leave the autoclicker running until the key 'F6' is pressed.")
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
    msg.exec()

# --- main ---

app = QApplication([])

show_message()

my_app = MyApp()
my_app.show()

app.exec()
```

Eventually run it in `__init__` before `self.show()`

---

If you want to show it after showing main window then do run it in `__init__` after `self.show()`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox

# --- classes ---

class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.show()
        self.show_message()

    def show_message(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Initial information')
        msg.setText("Please use the 'Close (F6)' button to close the program.\n\n"
                    "Closing it by pressing the red X button on the top will "
                    "leave the autoclicker running until the key 'F6' is pressed.")
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msg.exec()

# --- functions ---

# --- main ---

app = QApplication([])

my_app = MyApp()

app.exec()
```

---

If you want to show it with some delay then you could use `QTimer` for this.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

# --- classes ---

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.show()

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.show_message)
        timer.setSingleShot(True)
        timer.start(3000) # 3s

    def show_message(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Initial information')
        msg.setText("Please use the 'Close (F6)' button to close the program.\n\n"
                    "Closing it by pressing the red X button on the top will "
                    "leave the autoclicker running until the key 'F6' is pressed.")
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msg.exec()

# --- main ---

app = QApplication([])

my_app = MyApp()

app.exec()
```